# Broken `laravel-mix` and `npm watch` after installing `react-addons-css-transition-group` NPM package

Tags: reactjs, npm, laravel-mix

I am working on a `laravel` project with `reactjs`.

When I installed `react-addons-css-transition-group` the following message was displayed:

```
+ react-addons-css-transition-group@15.6.0
added 5 packages and removed 1124 packages in 68.535s
```

After that `laravel-mix` and `npm watch` do not work.

The following message is displayed when `npm watch` is executed:

```
'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch" "--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\wamp64\www\test\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Tidied up formatting.  Clarified title of question.  Clarified what are commands/package names.

Comment: This package https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html